# wxpython close parent on click button

Tags: button, wxpython, parent

I've been searching all morning for what should be the simplest thing ever but I'm either not looking in the right places or not understanding the answers I'm reading as everything I've tried has failed so far.

I'm creating a dialog with a label, a text input box and a Save button. The user enters text in the box, clicks on save and the text is saved to a variable and the dialogue should close. I can't get the last bit to happen. The closest I've come is destroying the button and the grey background but leaving the panel itself intact. I'm looking for some sort of KillParent solution... My main issue is that when I click the button I need two separate things to happen (save and exit) so when I call the on click function once I have done the variable saving I no longer have control to kill the main window. I know it's really elementary stuff but I just can't figure it out.

```
class ShowConnString(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    self.saveButton =wx.Button(self, label="Save", pos=(360, 50))

    self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label="ConnectionString:", pos=(20,20))
    self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="server='(local)', database='Audit', uid='sa', pwd='_PWD4sa_'", pos=(125, 18), size=(600,-1))

    self.saveButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SaveConnString)

def SaveConnString(self, event):
    self.editname.SelectAll()
    self.connstringtext = self.editname.GetStringSelection()
    print (self.connstringtext)
```

Comment: Have you tried `self.Destroy()`

Comment: Yes. Self.destroy() kills the inside of the box, I.e. the button, the grey background and the text box, but the frame itself still displays with a darker grey colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit messy but I don't have time to clean it up at the moment, it should use a sizer in the showconnstring class.

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Dialog Test",size=(500,400))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(400,300),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.VSCROLL)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Click me")
        sizer.Add(self.log, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

    def OnButton(self,event):
        dlg = ShowConnString(parent = self.panel) 
        dlg.ShowModal()
        if dlg.result_name:
            self.log.AppendText("Name: "+dlg.result_name+"\n")
            self.log.AppendText("Spin: "+str(dlg.result_spin)+"\n")
            self.log.AppendText("Choice: "+str(dlg.result_choice)+"\n")
        else:
            self.log.AppendText("No selection made\n")
        dlg.Destroy()

class ShowConnString(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Save", size= (650,220))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)

        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Connection", pos=(20,20))
        self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="server=127.0.0.1", pos=(110,20), size=(500,-1))
        self.lbl_1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, ("Spin Control"), pos=(20,60))
        self.spin = wx.SpinCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "", min=1, max=10, pos=(110,60))
        self.lbl_2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, ("Choice"),pos=(20,100))
        self.choice = wx.Choice(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, choices=[("Choice 1"), ("Choice 2"), ("Choice 3")], pos=(110,100))
        self.saveButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Save", pos=(110,160))
        self.closeButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Cancel", pos=(210,160))
        self.saveButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SaveConnString)
        self.closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnQuit)
        self.spin.SetValue(0)
        self.choice.SetSelection(0)
        self.Show()

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.result_name = None
        self.Destroy()

    def SaveConnString(self, event):
        self.result_name = self.editname.GetValue()
        self.result_spin = self.spin.GetValue()
        self.result_choice = self.choice.GetSelection()
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I don't get the 'result' thing. Is it supposed to be a built in property? Which classes have it? When I try to print dlg.result from the calling class it fails with AttributeError: 'ShowConnString' object has no attribute 'result'. Same with the call to ShowConnString with the parameter self.panel  - dlg = ShowConnString(parent = self.panel) == AttributeError: 'Audit' object has no attribute 'Panel'

Comment: I have added more options in the dialog, to show the sort of things that you can do. The "result things" are defined in `def SaveConnString`. Note that the class ShowConnString(wx.Dialog) is a dialog as is its `__init__`. If in doubt run my code as is.

Comment: Got it, finally! Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to sub-class a `wx.TextEntryDialog` but using `wx.Panel`.
You will probably find much simpler to just use a `wx.TextEntryDialog` directly i.e.

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None,"Connection String:","Save","server='(local)', database='Audit', uid='sa', pwd='_PWD4sa_'")
dlg.SetSize((600,180))
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    text = dlg.GetValue()
    print text
dlg.Destroy()
```

Comment: I could do that but I need to add a few extra buttons and text objects to the dialog, so that's why I made the class. I'm completely lost at this stage though, I think I've bitten off more than I can chew! I'm creating a frame in the main class which then hosts the panel from the called class and it's this frame that's not being destroyed. If I don't make the frame in the main app I can't get it to display. I've gone about this the complete wrong way and now I can't fix it at all, so I think my best bet is to start again from scratch.